# How to detect the CTRL-Key state in the onChange() handler for an HTML select element

Tags: asp.net, webforms, listbox, dom-events, onchange

**I want to handle the change event of a select element depending on whether the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-Key is pressed, but it does not work.**

Here's what I have: An ASP.NET WebForms ListBox control (that renders to a select element with options like so (slightly simplified):

```
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MultiselectDropDownStatus" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MultiselectDropDownStatus" size="7" multiple="multiple">
    <option selected="selected" value="">All</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Now, when the user selects one option, I want to do something depending on the state of the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-Key. I will handle the change event like so:

```
script.AppendLine(@"        $(""#" + ClientID + @""").change(function (e) {");
//....
```

Inside the script method I want to check the key state

```
script.AppendLine(@"            if (e.ctrlKey) {");
script.AppendLine(@"                alert(""ctr key was pressed during the click"")");
script.AppendLine(@"            }");
//...
```

**However, this way, the `e.crtlKey` is always `undefined`.**

But, when I handle the click event of the listbox control directly (not via the change event), like so:

```
script.AppendLine(@"        $(""#" + ClientID + @""").click(function (e) {");
script.AppendLine(@"            if (e.ctrlKey) {");
script.AppendLine(@"                alert(""ctr key was pressed during the click"")");
script.AppendLine(@"            }");
```

**Here, the `e.crtlKey` gives me the correct value.**

**Why can I not get the CTRL-Key state correctly in the change handler?**

I am working with IE 11 right now, but it should also work on other major browsers.

*Update: Originally I wanted to handle the event of having multiple selections using the CTRL key state. I realised that this was wrong and now  I have solved this by explicitly counting the selected options. However, this question remains valid, and thus I will leave it here: How to detect the key state in the changed handler?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. The change event does not define `ctrlKey`, as you have noted.

[change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) is an event which uses the [base event interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event), which does not handle `ctrlKey`.
To have `ctrlKey` defined, you need to use a [TouchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent), [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent), or [KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent).

In your example, `click` leads to `change` being triggered. `click`, being a MouseEvent, has the `ctrlKey` information, but `change` does not.

If desired you could have a global variable updated in the click event which would indicate if ctrlKey was pressed and then use that within the change event.